# cfchart xml styling is not working in CF16

Tags: coldfusion

I am using cfchart for generating chart, but xml content style is not working on coldfusion 16 but it is worked in CF10.Error image is attached.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbN6b.png)

Comment: please share your CF code

Comment: CF switched charting libraries between 10 and 2016, so I'm afraid you'll just have to redo them to fit the system.